# Git get commit relative to another commit

Tags: git

```
Commits

a0
b1
c2 <-
d3
e4
```

I need to add some changes to c2. Usually I would do:

```
git rebase -i d3    // Or @~3
```

Is there a way to do it just **with c2** e.g.

```
git rebase -i c2^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange you haven't tried. Your command certainly works.

```
git rebase -i c2^
```

or

```
git rebase -i c2~
```

(One caret is equivalent to one tilde. See [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) to understand the difference and to learn how to navigate commits graph.)

Comment: I tried it serveral times with slightly different approaches. Maybe I had some unstaged files and didn't read carefully. Embarrassing first question on Stackoverflow after years of just reading.